# Confidence of Probability Estimate

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

[image]

What is the difference between 
increasing the probability estimate a
and
increasing the confidence of the probability estimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Increasing the confidence" refers to the fact that Naive Bayes gives more weight to features that violate the independence assumption, for example, correlated features. That is explained very nicely in the paper [Tackling the Poor Assumptions of Naive Bayes Text Classifiers](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf), and proposes remedies for the shortcomings of Naive Bayes. Worth reading.